# Drupal 7 - Custom Module - Submit a form and show results in another page

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I have a custom module that has a form (checkboxes, select and a submit button).

When I click the submit button, I'm calling some functions in a .inc file that give me some data. One of these functions gives me an array that I want to show as a table in a summary page.

So, what I need is to submit the form and redirect the user to a "results page". I need to have the table data and the inputs of the form accessible in that results page.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: You  are going to have to store the submitted form values somewhere. There are many options. Can I ask why you are not just creating a content type for this?

Comment: I have a content type for the data I'm manipulating. The form I created asks for some inputs and make some calculations. After those calculations I want to show some results. I don't need that data to be stored. In the future I may add some "results data" to a new content type but not necessarily the data that I want to show in the results page.

Comment: maybe leveraging the drupal form ajax api to update the page with the results. Or simply creating a path via the HOOK_menu and making the form submit to that page.

Comment: So I just need to define the path in the HOOK_menu? I tried that and it says the path doesn't exist. I'm really confused with this one. The only examples I can find are for form_alter or they don't show the submit to another page.